# How to output a file from CodeIgniter without forcing download?

Tags: codeigniter, header, download

There seem to be lots of solutions out there for CodeIgniter to force download of a file, but I can't find any for outputting a file without forcing a download.

In my case, I've redirected my file downloads through a controller (originally Apache handled them directly) in order to log statistics. I used the CodeIgniter force_download function in the download helper. However, I've now had a request that some or all files should be able to be opened in the browser, such that saving to a file isn't forced, so I'm wanting to know how to do it.

Presumably, it's mostly a matter of outputting the right header, though I don't know whether different headers will be required for different file types. Has anyone got an example?

Comment: `all files should be able to be opened in the browser`. but which format pdf/excel/doc ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just have to specify the good mime-type and omit `Content-Disposition: attachment`.

So if the browser can render it, it will be display. If it can't, it will be download.

example:

```
$file = 'images/smileys/panda.gif';

if (file_exists($file)) 
{
    $finfo  = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME);

    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: '.$finfo->file($file));
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    readfile($file);
    exit;
}
```

Comment: A couple of things I discovered along the way: Don't put the content-type in quotes, but if you specify a filename, then *do* put it in quotes, or a comma in the filename will cause a duplicate header error.  The default filename, should a download be triggered, can be specified like this:
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="July Report.pdf"');